# Qt - setMenuBar() - EXC_BAD_ACCESS error - how to re-setMenuBar()

Tags: macos, qt

I am trying to create an application that shows a QMainWindow and multiple QWidget as additional windows.
Each window's menu is slightly different. My problem is on MAC.

What I did was to create a

```
MainWindow::updateMenuBar( QMenuBar * menu )
{
#ifdef Q_QS_MAC
this->setMenuBar(menu)
#endif
}
```

When I create the MainWindow, the this->setMenuBar(menu1) works fine and menu1 is set.
When I create additional windows, this->setMenuBar(menu2) or (menu3) or (...) are set correctly in the moment of the creation.
But when I change focus, and I call the function updateMenuBar(menu1) for example, the application crashes and I get the error:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, ...) within the updateMenuBar(...) method.

Does any of you know if I can continuously re-setMenuBar? And how to solve the problem?